# Python LMT to GMT offset -0001

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to convert a time to UTC time with the below code

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
st = dt.datetime.strptime("16:35:00", '%H:%M:%S')
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
st = st.replace(tzinfo=tz)
print(st.strftime(fmt))
st = st.astimezone(tz=pytz.utc)    
print(st.strftime(fmt))
```

It prints

```
1900-01-01 16:35:00 LMT-0001
1900-01-01 16:36:00 UTC+0000
```

Why is the offset 1 minute?

note:I am using python 3 in a jupyter notebook here

Comment: I'm guessing because Greenwich is not in the heart of London? It's probably just enough east of it to cause a (rounded?) 1 minute difference.

Comment: it definitely takes you an hour to get there with London's public transport.

Comment: That's because you should use a [bike or a boat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhlwNrZ4QIk) to get anywhere in London.